# Testing kendoGrid data using cucumber capybara

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui, cucumber, capybara, kendo-grid

I'm attempting to write some cucumber/capybara tests to validate data in a KendoGrid UI component and am having some real trouble determining how to select and validate the data on the page.

I've found the basic tutorials and examples on utlizing cucumber/capybara with table data but it appears that KendoGrid utilizing a slightly different configuration of it's tables and data where 1.) there is no "id" to easily select the grid on the page and 2.) there are multiple tables (one for the header) and another for the actual data itself.

Here is an excerpt of my current kendoGrid data I want to check:

```
<div id="item_grid" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-secondary" style="">
  <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
      <table role="grid">
        <colgroup>
          <col>
          <col>
          <col>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="ItemA" data-title="Item A" class="k-header" data-role="sortable">
              <a class="k-link" href="#">Item A</a>
            </th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="ItemB" data-title="Item B" class="k-header" data-role="sortable">
              <a class="k-link" href="#">Item B</a>
            </th>
            <th role="columnheader" data-field="ItemC" data-title="Item C" class="k-header" data-role="sortable">
              <a class="k-link" href="#">Item C</a>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="k-grid-content">
  <table role="grid">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-uid="2c77ea57-50ea-474d-950a-8379b3690936" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell">A</td>
        <td role="gridcell">223.63</td>
        <td role="gridcell">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="979534bc-7dea-47e9-9471-088c5bffe5b5" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell">B</td>
        <td role="gridcell">223.63</td>
        <td role="gridcell">180</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="4d4c31e7-4daf-44ad-b6c1-20ffdfde57c4" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell">C</td>
        <td role="gridcell">143.58</td>
        <td role="gridcell">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="8d315558-b014-4219-b21b-dbe52cc6dd18" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell">D</td>
        <td role="gridcell">143.58</td>
        <td role="gridcell">180</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is the best place to start for writing tests to cover this scenario?

I have done some additional playing with the Telerik Test Studio and testing this specific scenario in that application is extremely easy!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do - ie what in the control do you need help extracting with Capybara?

Comment: I would like to be able to validate that in the content it looks like rows with data such as ... A | 223.63 | 0, B | 223.63 | 180, C | 143.58 | 0, D | 143.58 | 180

Comment: So you need help with the extracting values (ie the Capybara part) or the validation part (ie the Cucumber part)?

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is the best way to approach extracting and validating. Keeping in mind that the id values of the data are dynamic and don't persist between loads.

The only constant you can rely on is the <div id="item_grid"> being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to collect the table of data into a 2D array using:

```
data_rows = page.all(:css, 'div#item_grid div.k-grid-content tr')
data = data_rows.collect do |tr|
  tr.all(:css, 'td').collect(&:text)
end
p data
#=> [["A", "223.63", "0"], ["B", "223.63", "180"], ["C", "143.58", "0"], ["D", "143.58", "180"]]
```

Then with the data (and assuming you know what data should be in the table), you can validate the data array:

```
# If you want to validate the entire table and row order matters:
expect(data).to eql([["A", "223.63", "0"], ["B", "223.63", "180"], ["C", "143.58", "0"], ["D", "143.58", "180"]])

# If you want to validate the entire table and row order does not matter:
expect(data).to match_array([["B", "223.63", "180"], ["A", "223.63", "0"], ["D", "143.58", "180"], ["C", "143.58", "0"]])    

# If you want to validate a specific row exists:
expect(data).to include(["B", "223.63", "180"])
```

Comment: Justin, I gave that a whirl in my test application and am now getting an error saying the actual collection contained [] and is missing the "correct" data. I'm guessing this has to do with the the css selection not picking it up correctly? I tinkered with the 'div#item_grid div.k-grid-content table tr' and that didn't seem to make a difference. Any thoughts?

Comment: Odd, the code worked fine when I made a page with the html provided. Are you sure you are testing against the right page - ie do you get the same html you posted when you do `p page.html`?

Comment: I think I found my problem here. The issue is that the element I'm testing against is a kendoGrid UI component that isn't always visible on the screen. A few of the steps prior to the validation make that item visible. The issue is there is a race condition where it is checking for content that isn't visible ... I have validated this by simply putting a pause and stepping through it slowly and giving the system time to display the data prior to validating.

Guess I need to brush up on how to have it wait ;-). Thanks!

Comment: I see, `all` does not wait like `find` does. To ensure that there is at least 1 table row loaded (and assuming that one loaded means they are all loaded), you could add a `page.find(:css, 'div#item_grid div.k-grid-content tr', :match => :first)` before getting the data rows.